# Android EditText vertical sizing: I want it to be small!

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-edittext

Here are sample pictures of two `EditText` fields I've added in an Action Bar:
[image: This is from the Graphical View]

[This is from the Graphical Layout tool in Eclipse]
[image]

[This is what it looks like in my emulator (2.1 WVGA854)

My question is, how can I make the `EditText` look a bit closer to the Graphical Layout?  Or is this a function of the emulation?  On my device, which has a custom rom, the `EditText` is square but looks similar to the Graphical Layout, which is what I want.

I've tried setting the textAppearance to `"@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`.  This does help in that it changes the size of the text within the EditText to be viewable, but it does not affect the size of the `EditText` itself.

Here's the XML for my EditText:

```
<EditText
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I could post the full XML, but essentially this EditText is enclosed (along with the search icon ImageView) in a RelativeLayout that is within another RelativeLayout.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
By request, here is the full XML for the top search bar:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBSearchOverlayMic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/aslctr_search_overlay_blackbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_ic_microphone" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVSearchOverlayDivider1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlayMic"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_division" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IVSearchOverlayDivider1"
        android:background="@drawable/aslctr_search_overlay_blackbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_ic_searchwhite" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_overlay_searchbg">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETSearchOverlaySearch"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/ETSearchOverlaySearch"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/search_actionbar_ic_searchcream" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your whole xml. or which layout you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the problem.  The issue was that the EditText was inside the RelativeLayout...I think that messed with the padding, or perhaps the EditText's layout_height="wrap_content" meant that it extended vertically.  Here's the reworked XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBSearchOverlayMic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/aslctr_search_overlay_blackbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_ic_microphone" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVSearchOverlayDivider1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlayMic"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_division" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IVSearchOverlayDivider1"
        android:background="@drawable/aslctr_search_overlay_blackbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/search_overlay_ic_searchwhite" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVSearchBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_overlay_searchbg" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="0dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/IBSearchOverlaySearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/search_actionbar_ic_searchcream" />
</RelativeLayout>
```